# Output of last week's date in PHP different between localhost and server

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to get the previous Monday (last week) and end of last week (Sunday) but when the code runs on the server it is different to when it's run on localhost.

This is my code:

```
$start_past = strtotime("last week"); 
$end_past = strtotime("+6 day",$start_past);

echo $start_past_qry = date("m/d/Y",$start_past);
echo $end_past_qry = date("m/d/Y",$end_past);
```

#### Results on localhost

- 05/06/2013
- 05/12/2013

#### Results on server

- 05/13/2013
- 05/19/2013

The results on the server seems to be fall under the current week. I want to get the last week range.

Comment: Please make sure of your server time and time zone

Comment: check if both server has same time zone & calendar settings.

Comment: It's the same. I think my code is wrong :D Please help

Comment: try echo date("c"); on both and show us the results

Comment: I did this by echoing this code 
$timezone = "Asia/Manila";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

but it doesn't appear. I cannot edit the date on the server because it has too many projects that may effect if I do it.

Comment: Then use `date_default_timezone_set()`

Answer (score 3):

From php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See **date_default_timezone_get()** on the various ways to define the default time zone.

you need to define default timezone which can be done by function

[date_default_timezone_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

[List of supported Time Zones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Also pay attention that:

> Prior to **PHP 5.3.0**, relative time formats supplied to the time argument of strtotime() such as this week, previous week, last week, and next week were interpreted to mean a 7 day period relative to the current date/time, rather than a week period of Monday through Sunday.

Be sure you have same php version and it is at least 5.3.0 Check [manual of strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to know more details

Answer (score 2):

```
$Current = Date('N');

$DaysToSunday = 7 - $Current; 

$DaysFromMonday = $Current - 1; 

$Sunday = Date('d/m/y', StrToTime("+ {$DaysToSunday} Days")) . "<br>"; 

$date = Date('Y/m/d', StrToTime("- {$DaysFromMonday} Days"));

$mod_date = strtotime($date."- 7 days");

echo $last_week_monday=date("Y/m/d",$mod_date) . "<br>";
```